# Cross-compiling blender on linux platform for windows target

Tags: windows, linux

I've successfully compiled Blender for linux on a linux system. However, I'd like to build a Windows version as well, using the same machine. I found some old forum posts about using MinGW32 to do this, but nothing very useful.
 Please reply if you've successfully cross-compiled Blender on linux for a windows target, and explain how.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about compiling blender. Unfortunately, due to the complex and specific nature of build environments it was viewed that compiling questions cannot be easily answered here. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems/400#400